# Set an expiration date using Use effect React Native, but screen does not re-render properly

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am working on an app where I need to filter by dates to show on a particular screen. The idea is anything within 30 days of today's date should be populated in the filter. I am trying to get that screen to render as soon as the app is opened but it only renders after playing around on other screens.
Here is the logic below. Any help is appreciated.

```
const ExpiringCertificationsScreen = () => {
  const { state, fetchCertifications } = useContext(CertificationContext);
  const [expiration, setExpiration] = useState([]);

  const diffDays = date => {
    let today = new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleDateString();
    let expire = new Date(date.toLocaleDateString());
    let difference = new Date(expire).getTime() - new Date(today).getTime();
    return difference / (1000 * 3600 * 24);
  };

  const filterExpirationDate = state.filter(item => {
    return diffDays(new Date(item.expirationDate)) <= 30;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (filterExpirationDate.length > 0) {
      console.log(filterExpirationDate);
      setExpiration(filterExpirationDate);
    } else {
      console.log('Down');
    }
  }, []);

  if (expiration.length === 0) {
    return (
      <Body>
        <Text style={styles.title}>EXPIRING SOON</Text>
        <Text style={{ margin: 15 }}>
          There aren't any certifications expiring soon
        </Text>
      </Body>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Body>
      <Text style={styles.title}>EXPIRING SOON</Text>
      <ScrollView style={{ marginTop: 15 }}>
        <FlatList
          data={expiration}
          keyExtractor={item => item._id}
          renderItem={({ item }) => {
            return (
              <Certifications
                title={item.title}
                month={item.expirationDate}
                description={item.description}
                id={item._id}
              />
            );
          }}
        />
      </ScrollView>
    </Body>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your code as per your requirement.. Please check and acknowledge

```js
const ExpiringCertificationsScreen = () => {
   const { state, fetchCertifications } = useContext(CertificationContext);
   const [expiration, setExpiration] = useState([]);

   const diffDays = date => {
     let today = new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleDateString();
     let expire = new Date(date.toLocaleDateString());
     let difference = new Date(expire).getTime() - new Date(today).getTime();
     return difference / (1000 * 3600 * 24);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
     const filterExpirationDate = state.filter(item => {
         return diffDays(new Date(item.expirationDate)) <= 30;
     });        
      console.log(filterExpirationDate);
      setExpiration(filterExpirationDate);
  }, [state]);

  return expiration.length === 0 ? (
      <Body>
        <Text style={styles.title}>EXPIRING SOON</Text>
        <Text style={{ margin: 15 }}>
          There aren't any certifications expiring soon
        </Text>
      </Body>
  ) :(
    <Body>
      <Text style={styles.title}>EXPIRING SOON</Text>
      <ScrollView style={{ marginTop: 15 }}>
        <FlatList
          data={expiration}
          keyExtractor={item => item._id}
          renderItem={({ item }) => {
            return (
              <Certifications
                title={item.title}
                month={item.expirationDate}
                description={item.description}
                id={item._id}
              />
            );
          }}
        />
      </ScrollView>
    </Body>
  );
};
```